# How do i make a Plotting Graph App GUI using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, graph

I am trying to make a GUI based program that takes a function from the user and displays its graph. The functions input are basic plots like y = x or something like that.

On running the following code, I experience an error only after entering the function (Say I entered *x* in the entry box e1). -- **invalid literal for int() with base 10.**

What changes should I make to run it correctly?

*PS: I am newbie! Please be simple with the language. Thanks~~*

```
from tkinter import *
from numpy import *

def graph():

    function = Entry.get(e1)
    function = int((function))
    n1 = Entry.get(e2)
    n1 = int((n1))
    n2 = Entry.get(e3)
    n2 = int((n2))

    x_cords = range(n1,n2+1)
    y_cords = [(function) for x in x_cords]


    plt.plot(x_cords,y_cords)
    plt.show()

    return 0

main_window = Tk()
main_window.title("Grapher")

l1 = Label(main_window, text="Enter your function: ").grid(row=0,column=0)
l2 = Label(main_window, text="Enter your starting range: ").grid(row=1,column=0)
l3 = Label(main_window, text="Enter your end range: ").grid(row=2,column=0)

e1 = Entry(main_window, bd = 10, relief = RIDGE)#, textvariable = function)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2 = Entry(main_window, bd = 10, relief = RIDGE)#, textvariable = n)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
e3 = Entry(main_window, bd = 10, relief = RIDGE)
e3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

b1 = Button(main_window, text="Graph", command = graph).grid(row=3, column=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```